# Line feed is being removed from echo when called in double-quotes

Tags: bash, echo, sh

I'm trying to populate a shell variable called `$recipient` which should contain a value followed by a new-line.

```
$ set -x # force bash to show commands as it executes them
```

I start by populating `$user`, which is the value that I want to be followed by the newline.

```
$ user=user@xxx.com
+ user=user@xxx.com
```

I then call `echo $user` inside a double-quoted command substitution. The `echo` statement should create a newline after `$user`, and the double-quotes should preserve the newline.

```
$ recipient="$(echo $user)"
++ echo user@xxx.com
+ recipient=user@xxx.com
```

However when I print `$recipient`, I can see that the newline has been discarded.

```
$ echo "'recipient'"
+ echo ''\''recipient'\'''
'recipient'
```

I've found the same behaviour under bash versions 4.1.5 and 3.1.17, and also replicated the issue under dash.

I tried using "printf" rather than echo; this didn't change anything.

Is this expected behaviour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Command substitution removes trailing newlines.  From the [standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_03):

The shell shall expand the command substitution by executing command in a subshell environment (see Shell Execution Environment ) and replacing the command substitution (the text of command plus the enclosing "$()" or backquotes) with the standard output of the command, removing sequences of one or more  characters at the end of the substitution. Embedded  characters before the end of the output shall not be removed; however, they may be treated as field delimiters and eliminated during field splitting, depending on the value of IFS and quoting that is in effect. If the output contains any null bytes, the behavior is unspecified.

You will have to explicitly add a newline.  Perhaps:

```
recipient="$user
"
```

There's really no reason to use a command substitution here.  (Which is to say that `$(echo ...)` is almost always a silly thing to do.)

Answer (score 1):

All shell versions will react the same way, this is nothing new in scripting.

The new-line at the end of your original assignment is not included in the variable's value. It only "terminates" the current cmd and signals the shell to process.

Maybe user="user@xxx.com\n" will work, but without context about why you want this, just know that people usually keep variables values separate from the formatting "tools" like the newline.

IHTH.